# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure to calculate time difference

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table with two columns `TotalTime` and `ElapsedTime`, each of type `varchar(8)` and the data in the columns looks this this:

```
7:00:00, 6:12:30
```

(meaning *days:hours:minutes*)

I would like to create a stored procedure called `SubtractTime` which will calculate `TotalTime - ElapsedTime` (e.g. `7:00:00 - 6:12:30 = 00:11:30`).

What would be the syntax for such a function?

Comment: Egads. Why are you storing time as a string? If this is a duration, store it as an integer in minutes.

Comment: You're right, doing it with minutes is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`DATEDIFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28SQL.105%29.aspx). Of course, you'd have to cast those varchars to datetime.